# Highlight duplicate value by range in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet:

[image]

I need type value into 2 columns: [Supervisor 1] and [Supervisor 2] by condition:

1. Value into [Supervisor 1] column and [Supervisor 2] column must different. If the value is the same so highlight red color (both of them)

Ex:

In D3 cell, I type "John" value. In E3 cell, I type "Susan" value -> No highlight red color

In D3 cell, I type "John" value. In E3 cell, I type "John" value -> Both of D3 and E3 cells highlight red color

In D4 cell, I type "John" value. In E9 cell, I type "John" value -> Both of D3 and E3 cells highlight red color

2. The highlight red color just occur in range on this day

Ex:

In D3 cell, I type "John" value. In E10 cell, I type "John" value -> No highlight red color

In D21 cell, I type "Mary" value. In E13 cell, I type "Mary" value -> No highlight red color

Please help me this problem

--------------------I updated my expect result--------------------

I have a image (my expect result)

[image]

In E5 cell, after I type "Louis" value -> highlight red color. Because value in E5 and D4 the same (Note: on this day)

In E7 cell, after I type "Nemo" value -> highlight red color. Because value in E7 and D7 the same (Note: on this day)

In D15 cell, after I type "Messi" value -> highlight red color. Because value in D15 and E12 the same (Note: on this day)

In D15 cell, after I type "Messi" value -> highlight red color. Because value in D15 and E12 the same (Note: on this day)

In D11 cell, after I type "Susan" value -> **NOT** highlight red color. Because value in D11 and D6 the same but different day exam (Note: on different day)

In E21 cell, after I type "Chen" value -> highlight red color. Because value in E21 and D21 the same (Note: on this day)

Comment: Just wondering, why is D12 (Messi) highlighted instead of E12 Messi? And why is E15 (Logan) highlighted?

Comment: Hello, Tom Sharpe, E15 (Logan) highlighted because it appear the second [the first appear in E10 (Logan) but in the range D10:E16], and D15 (Messi) highlighted because it appear the second [the first appear in E12 (Messi) but in the range D10:E16]. My expect result is each name Supervisor just appear only one in a range (by date)

Comment: Fine, it's still a COUNTIFS but slightly different. Note that Rooney will also be highlighted in D16 because he previously appeared in E13.

Comment: Hello, Tom Sharpe. Yes, this is my mistake In D16 (Rooney) must highlight because it appear the second [the first appear in E13 (Rooney)]. Thank you help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pick up *any* match between the two columns within the same day, and the day always takes 7 rows, try

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH($D3:$D9,$E3:$E9,0)))
```

[image]

The formula can be changed if my assumptions aren't correct.

EDIT

If you want to highlight the name in column E if it also appears in column D on the same date, it's just a COUNTIFS

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A3,D:D,E3)
```

[image]

EDIT 2

To highlight the *second* occurrence only of the name for the same date, you would need two formulae

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A3,$D$2:$D2,D3)+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A3,$E$2:$E2,D3)
```

for D3:D23

and

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A3,$A3,$D$2:$D3,E3)+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A3,$E$2:$E2,E3)
```

for E3:E23.

[image]

Comment: Hello Tom Sharpe, Thank you your solution but I want the general formula.

Comment: Hello, Tom Sharpe. I tried your solution but the case following don't solve yet: 1. In E15 (Logan) must highlight because it appear the second [the first appear in E10 (Logan)]. 2. In D15 (Messi) must highlight because it appear the second [the first appear in E12 (Messi)]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too hard to do... the key insight is that you can use a cell-relative formula within a conditional formatting rule. (You'll need two... one for each cell to check if it matches the other in the pair. If they match, then that triggrs the conditional format.)`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

I have your solution:

Select the whole range for Column D (looking the picture, I will assume its D3:D23.

In Ribbon, select Home > "Conditional Formatting" > New Rule.

Select Option: "Use a Formula to determine which cells to format".
In "Format values where this formula is true" add the following formula: `=IF(D3<>0,IF(D3=E3,1,0))`

Select the format you want for the cell, clicking in "Format", if D and E are the same and press "Ok".

Now do the same steps for Column E (selecting the whole range for column E), but instead add the following formula: `=IF(E3<>0,IF(D3=E3,1,0))`

This should definitely solve your issue. If there is a question, please let me know.

Comment: Hello, @Lucas Poloni Cordeiro, The first thank you so much your interesting in my problem. But I expect another result. Please see again my problem (I updated)

Comment: Apologies, I misread your answer. I can make it work if you are whiling to edit the conditional format for each day. If not, which I believe you wont, it will need the use of VBA. That is because when you match the whole table, there are several matching for each case = Excel formulas does not know how to go to the next match if a condition does not fulfill.